# Converting bytecode of Solidity smart contract back to its original state

Tags: blockchain, bytecode, solidity, decompiler, contract

If I deploy a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain and I don't want anyone else to see the content of my code, could they see it by converting the bytecode of the contract -easily- using some kind of tool/decompiler/decryption? For example I may want to make a contract that contains sensitive info of clients.

edit: I have found [this](https://ethervm.io/decompile) that converts it to Assembly, but is it possible for someone to read the original code, for example the values/strings/data of the clients I have inserted.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Currently the best decompiler is [Eveem](https://eveem.org/). It outputs a sort of pseudo-python that can't be used to recompile but is fairly readable.

In general you should assume that all information deployed to the blockchain can be seen by everyone. Reading raw bytecode is not an obstacle for someone who is sufficiently technically proficient.